# Multiple xml file are not able to save on file server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> I have written below method to write xml file in given path,and this method i called from foreach loop. for the first call it will create a new file on file server but when its comes for second call it will not generate the file on file server.

```
public string WriteXMLStringToFile(string astrXML, string astrfolderName)
{
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(astrXML))
      {
        string lstrFileName = ICON.busGlobal.GetSystemDate().ToString(DATE_FORMAT_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS);
string istrPath = utlPassInfo.iobjPassInfo.isrvDBCache.GetPathInfo(astrfolderName) + "\\" + lstrFileName + FILE_FORMAT_XML;
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(istrPath))
  {

   file.Write(astrXML);
  }
}
return istrPath;
```

Comment: Are you sure its not simply overwriting the same file?  The file name does not appear to be unique if its called more than once per second.

Comment: Yes alex, I'm sure that and I mentioned the date time for every file name.

Comment: Super sure? If you run that in a tight loop lstrFileName will be the same and any existing file will be overwritten as the date time wont change.  To test use `lstrFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` to generate unique file names, run the code and see if you end up with a bunch of files.

Comment: Thanks lot Alex, It work using Guid.NewGuid().ToString();